# How to divide a line of numbers into N groups such that the sums of each group are closest to their mean?

Tags: algorithm, list

I have the following problem: I have M numbers arranged into a line. I need to divide the line into N groups such that the sums of the numbers of each group are closest to the mean of these sums by some metric. The actual metric is not important: we can choose to minimize sum of absolute differences, or variance, etc., depending on which leads to the simplest solution.

A similar problem is partitioning of sets, which is NP Hard. However, here we have additional constraint: groups must pack successive numbers, so there might be a solution that doesn't involve brute-force search. The numbers are large.

**EDIT**

Example:

Numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, need to divide into 3 groups

Let's say we want to minimize sum of absolute differences (SAD).

Groups: (1) 1 2 3 4 5 6 (sum = 21); (2) 7 8 (sum = 15); (3) 9 10 (sum = 19)

Mean = (21+15+19)/3 = 18.33, SAD = 21-18.33 + 18.33-15 + 19-18.33 = 6.67 <- That's what we want to minimize.

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and expected output?

Comment: I am not sure this problem statement makes sense and I cannot understand it. You say "the sums of each group are closest to the mean of these sums": do you mean that you want to minimize the dispersion of the sums of the groups ? If this is the case, I expect that the groups will be highly imbalanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know what the sum should be, then you can make groups that are close to this sum. If your metrics are nice then you should be able to use binary search to find what the actual sum is. When you are aiming for a particular sum you could go through the list adding numbers to a group until the groups sum goes over the sum size. Then either take or don't take this last integer. go through the entire list doing this and see what groups sum deviated the most from the sum. Then go back through the list trying combinations of group sizes that fall within the deviation.. it should be fast enough. Otherwise use dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array in descending order and 
have three numbers storing sums
iterate over the loop and add the current number to the minimum sum
answer is (10,5,4),(9,6,3),(8,7,2,1)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int maximum(int x, int y, int z) {
int max = x; /* assume x is the largest */

if (y > max) { /* if y is larger than max, assign y to max */
    max = y;
} /* end if */

if (z > max) { /* if z is larger than max, assign z to max */
    max = z;
} /* end if */

return max; /* max is the largest value */
} 

int main()
 {
int array[] = {1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
int part1=0;
int part2=0;
int part3=0;

sort(array,array+size,greater<int>());
for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
{
    if( part1 < part2 && part1 < part3)
    {
        part1 +=array[x];
    }else if(part2 < part3){
        part2 +=array[x];
    }else{
        part3 +=array[x];
    }
}

printf("first part1 = %d\n",part1 );
printf("first part2 = %d\n",part2 );
printf("first part3 = %d\n",part3 );

printf("-------------------------------\n");
printf("largest number = %d\n",maximum(part1,part2,part3));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I will use your example dividing the numbers 1..10 into three groups to illustrate my answer. The solution will apply to any set of numbers and any number of groups. Of sourse, when the size of the set of numbers is large you may not be able to use a brute force approach. Having said that, large sets of numbers can be handled in a similar way but more on that later.

Lets say we have M consecutive numbers, denoted (1..M), in the set and we want to divide these into N groups.

The first thing to determine is the value that you will compare the sum of each group to. This is simply the sum of the set of numbers divided by the the number of groups N.

In the example sumOf(1..M) = 55 and N = 3 so 55/3 = 18.33 is the value that each group should sum to. You want to minimise the difference between the group sums and 18.33

As another example, if you want to divide the set of numbers 1..20 into two groups then you will want to minimise the difference between the group sums and sumOf(1..20) = 210 divide by 2 groups  = 210/2 = 105.

The next step is to find all possible groups. This is another interesting problem nad given the restriction of proups containing consecutive numbers, the total number of groups combinations is not as many as you might expect.

Finding the combinations is a recursive problem and it is easy enough to work out a general equation.

lets start with a simple case. How many combinations of 10 numbers in the set (1..10). Well, there is only one group, the numbers (1..10)

Now, how many combinations of 2 groups in the 10 numbers. The answer is M-1 or 10-1 = 9, namely

```
(1),(2..10)
(1..2) (3..10)
(1..3) (4..10)
(1..4) (5..10)
(1..5) (6..10)
(1..6) (7..10)
(1..7) (8..10)
(1..8) (9..10)
(1..9) (10)
```

So a set of size M has M-1 combinations of groups. This is the basis of the recursion.

How many combinations of 3 groups in the 10 numbers.

Well, the first group will be one of the following

```
(1),(1..2),(1..3) ,(1..4) ,(1..5),(1..6) ,(1..7) ,(1..8)
```

Given any of these as the first group, lets work out how many combinations of 2 groups exist in the remaining numbers.

Let the first group of the three = (1). We have nine numbers left and know these can make 9-1 = 8 different combinations of 2 groups
Let the first group of the three = (1..5). We have five numbers left and these can make 5-1 = 4 different groups of 2 numbers.

So, in total we will have

```
(1) -> 8 combinations
(1..2) -> 7 combinations
(1..3) -> 6 combinations
(1..4) -> 5 combinations
(1..5) -> 4 combinations
(1..6) -> 3 combinations
(1..7) -> 2 combinations
(1..8) -> 1 combinations
```

giving SumOf(1..8) ,or in general (sum(1..M-2), combinations of groups. SumOf(1..8) = 8*9/2 = 36

So there are 36 combinations of 3 groups in 10 numbers where each group contains consecutive numbers.

as an aside, for 3 groups in 100 numbers you have sumOf(1..98) = 98*99/2 = 4851 combinations of groups, so as M increases you will get more combinations and as some value of M the brute force method may not be possible.

The approach outlined above can be used to design a simple recursive algorithm to get all combinations of groups in the set (1..M).

Also, a simple equation can be worked out for any number N of groups in a set of M numbers. For example, if you move to 4 groups in 10 numbers then you have situations like first group is (1..3), then find combinations of 3 groups in the remaining 7 nuumbers. There will be sum(1..M-2) = sum(1..5)..etc.

Anyway, back to the problem. You have all combinations of groups and so you can iterate through the groups and calculate the SAD for each combination and choose the one that minimises the SAD.

When the number of combinations is very large and you can't look at each combination then you could try bootstrapping to select groups at random or some kind of evolutionary algorithm approach where you start with a number of randomly chosen combinations and then randomly move numbers from one group to another and keep those that have the lowest SAD. Continue this step until you see no further improvement in SAD.

Or you might do as @Robert King suggested, starting out with a single combination and improving on it by moving numbers from one group to another.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get where you're coming from. As programmer I think of it in a numerical sequence, I have put something together quickly as its valentines and I'm going out for a meal :) Here is a simple version:

```
a = all numbers added together
b = number of groups
m = a/b (value is mean)

c = array(a)DES (add all numbers to an array in decending order)

foreach c
    if((m-(c[0] + c[1])) < (m-(c[0]))
        if((m-(c[0] + c[1] + c[2])) < (m-(c[0] + c[1])))
        else
        g1 = c[0],c[1]
        c = c - (c[0],c[1])

    else
    g1 = c[0]
    c = c - c[0]

foreach c
    if((m-(c[0] + c[1])) < (m-(c[0]))
    else
    g2 = c[0]
```

I have quickly put this together, so it may not be accurate but hopefully you can see the sequence and procedure. Ofcourse all of the 'c' values would be dynamically selected as would each 'foreach' loop. You could need a foreach statement at the end to handle any left over digits and add them to the value that would keep closest to the mean.

Happy valentines day!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working (though not thoroughly tested) JavaScript solution.

It essentially uses dynamic scripting to build the brute-force stacked for-loops (ordered combinations) to get the starting indexes for each group in the array.

```
var A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var G = 3;
function find(line, groups) {
    var length = line.length;
    var mean = line.sum() / groups;
    var temp = [0];
    var bestsad = 4294967295;
    var beststarts = [];
    var dynamic = "var x0 = 0; ";
    for(var i=1; i<groups; i++) {
        dynamic += "for(var x" + i + "=x" + (i-1) + "+1;x" + i + "<" + length + ";x" + i + "++) ";
        temp.push("x" + i);
    }
    dynamic += "{ var sad = getSAD(line, mean, [" + temp.join(",") + "]);";
    dynamic += "if(sad < bestsad) { bestsad = sad; beststarts = [" + temp.join(",") + "] ;} }"
    eval(dynamic);
    console.log("Best SAD " + bestsad);
    console.log("Best Start Indexes " + beststarts);
    return beststarts;
}
function getSAD(line, mean, starts) {
    var sums = [];
    var sad;
    for(var i = 0; i < starts.length-1; i++)
    {
        var idx = i;
        sums.push(line.slice(starts[idx], starts[i+1]).sum());
    }
    sums.push(line.slice(starts[starts.length-1]).sum());
    sad = sums.sad(mean);
    return sad;
}

Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    var result = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
        result += this[i];
    return result;
}
Array.prototype.sad = function(mean) {
    var result = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
        result += Math.abs(this[i] - mean);
    return result;
}
find(A, G);
```

Here's what the script that the **var dynamic** variable/string holds/executes.

```
var x0 = 0; 
for(var x1=x0+1;x1<10;x1++) 
 for(var x2=x1+1;x2<10;x2++) { 
  var sad = getSAD(line, mean, [0,x1,x2]);
  if(sad < bestsad) { 
   bestsad = sad; 
   beststarts = [0,x1,x2] ;
  } 
}
```

Why not just use group index vector + recursion? For this type of recursive problem the iterative method is optimal. Admittedly the overhead (and added complexity) from the dynamic scripting would negate any benefit on small arrays, but when working with actual data (large arrays) it'll churn out answers faster.